# Django database storage issue

Tags: python, mysql, django, multithreading

So I am running a particular code block in threads(5), and in the code been executed by the threads data are been saved to the database. e.g.

link = AccountLinkModel.objects.create(account=account)

if I print the value of "link" object and any field from the AccountLinkModel model, they print successfully, which means the data was created, but eventually, the record of some was not found in the Database, only few were recorded in the database.

Any advice on what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to run it with only 1 thread to see if the problem still occurs, if not you might have a race condition in your code where you are not properly locking a shared ressource of your threads.

Comment: i just tested, it worked on a single thread.

what do you mean by locking a shared resource.

Comment: If threads access the same objects then you need to use locks to avoid race conditions, here is a tutorial: https://www.pythontutorial.net/advanced-python/python-threading-lock/

Comment: locking the write query doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

> if I print the value of "link" object and any field from the AccountLinkModel model, they print successfully, which means the data was created.

If the `create` function is wraped by a transaction block like

```py
with transaction.atomic:
    link = AccountLinkModel.objects.create(account=account)
   ...other db stuff
```

Then the object is not persistet at the database after the create funktion was called. If you print after the create call, then that are just the python attributes from the ram.

Comment: there is no atomic transaction lock wrapped around the code block.

Comment: Are there any error messages from the django orm or so on?

Comment: no error, 
it even shows that the record was created and the ID can be printed

Comment: Ok is the id generated by the db it self or on the fly from orm layer like uuid?

Comment: Maybe you could add or link more from your code base to debug them. I wrote a lot of multithreading code with django + celery.

Comment: i think the id is from orm layer

Comment: Ok, so it is still not clear if the commit is done with the create function... Could you pls post more of your code?

Comment: an atomic transaction was wrapped around the parent, when It was removed, it seems to be working properly when tested with small data, it has not been tested with large traffic yet though.

Comment: OK - it would be helpfull if you post a code snippet